# Symfony2 Form Class Builder

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I've never tried building a form like this so looking to see if anyone has a solution doing this the Symfony way.

So example code is below minus annotation and getter setters just to save space :)

```
 //Entity
 Class Location {
      private $id;
      private $name;
      // one to many annotation is here
      private $properties;
 }


 Class Property {
     private $id;
     private $name;
     // many to one
     private $location
 }

 //Controller code
 class SomeController {
     //anotation for route etc ;)
     public function someAction(Request $request){

           //Returns all locations and there properties (only 4 locations)
           $locations = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('LocationEntity')->findAllWithProperties();

        $form = $this->createForm(new needHelpHereType(), $locations);
     }
 }
```

So how would i create a form that does the followig?

- foreach entity in this array create a new collection type for properties.

So to give you an idea of screen presentation it would like something like this.

Name of Location 1
Collection of properties for Location 1

Name of Location 2
Collection of properties for Location 2

Name of Location 3
Collection of properties for Location 3

Name of Location 4
Collection of properties for Location 4

Your help is appreciated :)

Answer (score -1):

I think `CollectionType` is your solution,
checkout following link [here.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi motammem.  I've marked down your answer as you have not provided an example of how to use this where the parent is initiated by an array collection of entities not a single entity. Please provide an example and I'd be more than happy to change your score :)